# React returns the height of only the last element from the list of elements

Tags: reactjs

I need to get height of each individual list item. I import `ArticlesMenuItem` in a parent component and I render them in this way:

```
const ArticlesMenu = () => {
    const articlesItemRef = useRef(null);
    const renderArticleItems = () => {
        return articleItems.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <ArticlesMenuItem 
                    path={item.path}     
                    label={item.label} 
                    key={item.id} 
                    innerRef={articlesItemRef}
                />
            )
        });
    }
    return (
        <div id="articles" className="clearfix">
            <h2 className="articles__heading">{articleItems.heading}</h2>
            <ul className="articles__list clearfix">
                {renderArticleItems()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I the `ArticlesMenuItem.js` file I want to know the height of each item. But console.log shows only the height of the last item. If the last item has height of 90, it shows 90 for all of the items. If it has 60, then 60 for all of them.

[image]

ArticleMenuItem.js looks like this:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ArticlesMenuItem = ({ path, id, label, innerRef }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
         console.log('innerRef', innerRef.current.clientHeight)
    }, [innerRef.current])

    return (
        <li className="articles__item" ref={innerRef}>
            <Link to={path} className="articles__link" >{label}</Link>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ArticlesMenuItem;
```

Why does it happen? How can I get real height of each of the items?

Comment: Is the same innerRef is getting passed for all items ?

Comment: please see how it is passed - I updated the description (I did not notice that I did not format properly the rendering in the parent component so it was not displayed in the question)

Comment: I think same useRef is passed for all elements, You can think of creating useRef inside ArticlesMenuItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add useRef as below in the ArticlesMenuItem itself

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ArticlesMenuItem = ({ path, id, label }) => {
    let ref = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
         console.log('innerRef', ref.clientHeight)
    }, [innerRef.current])

    return (
        <li className="articles__item" ref={ref}>
            <Link to={path} className="articles__link" >{label}</Link>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ArticlesMenuItem;
```

Comment: I will just edit your solution later - by removing `[innerRef.current]` from `useEffect`, and adding `current` to `ref` in `console.log`, to make it 100% working, but at the moment Stackoverflow does not let me to do it